# curl multi-handle keep-alive after getting 404

Tags: curl

I want to reuse a connection also after getting 404 from the server. 
Using easy-handle, I got this behavior by default.
Using multi-handle, after getting 404 I had to remove and add the handle (otherwise it doesn't perform the request at all), and then I got another connection.
B.T.W after OK response (200), removing and adding the handle doesn't affect the persistency. Is there a way to have this behavior also with 404 response?